# How to sort rows (strings) of 2d char array using strcmp?

Tags: c, arrays, sorting, for-loop, c-strings

So I need to sort the rows of a 2d char array. If user inputs:

1. wxyz
2. abdf
3. abcd
4. lmno
5. qrst

it should return

1. abcd
2. abdf
3. lmno
4. qrst
5. wxyz

   Though I am having an issue on my sorting method. Is it possible to sort without using pointers or should pointers be used? It even stores all user input into temp which is weird because it has a length of 5.

   ```
      #include <stdio.h>
      #include <string.h>
      void sortStr(char str[5][4]);

      int main()
   {
       char str[5][4];
       int i,r,c;



       //user inputs 5 strings in 2d array.
   for(i=0;i<5;i++)
   {
      printf("\nEnter a string %d: ",i+1);
      scanf(" %[^\n]",&str[i]);
   }

   sortStr(str);
   //display array
   for(r = 0; r<5; r++)
   {
       for(c=0; c<4; c++)
       {
           printf("%c",str[r][c]);
       }
       printf("\n");
   }

    return 0;
     }

   void sortStr(char str[5][4])
   {
       int i, j;
   char temp[5];
       //this sorts each row based
       for(i=0; i<5; i++){
               printf("T1:\n");
           for(j=i+1; j<4; j++)
           {
               printf("T2:\n");
               if(strcmp(str[i],str[j]) > 0)
               {
                   //testing where code crashes
                   printf("T3:\n");
                   strcpy(temp,str[i]);
                   printf("T4:\n");
                   printf("%s\n",temp);//temp has all user input. How?
                   strcpy(str[i],str[j]);//code crashes
                   printf("T5:\n");
                   strcpy(str[j],temp);
                   printf("T6:\n");
               }
           }
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: Big important thing: Remember that strings in C are *terminated* and you need space for the terminator as well in your arrays. That means if you have an array of four characters, it can only hold a string with *three* characters because the fourth has to be the terminator. If you put more than three characters in such an array, then you will go out of bounds and have *undefined behavior*.

Comment: You cannot really use arrays without using pointers, too. Why not use the standard `qsort`?

Comment: Im not to familiar with qsort. im still beginner programmer.

Comment: Are you a beginner reading, too? How about doning a little (re)search?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use `qsort` like this

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void){
    char str[5][5];//5 for read 4 character + null-terminator
    int i;

    for(i=0;i<5;i++){
        printf("\nEnter a string %d: ", i+1);
        scanf(" %4[^\n]", str[i]);
    }

    qsort(str, 5, sizeof(*str), (int (*)(const void*, const void*))strcmp);

    puts("");
    for(i=0;i<5;i++){
        puts(str[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```